# Find gcd (a:b) with some data

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

I want to know if this is correctly solved

> Find (a:b) knowing that the remainder from dividing $a$ by $b$ is
>   27and the remainder from dividing $b$ by $27$ is $21$

So, $r_{b}(a) = 27$ and $r_{27}(b) = 21$

What I did is to use the gcd property that says that $(a:b) = (b:r_{b}(a))$

So, by this property, $(a:b) = (b:r_{b}(a)) = (b:27) = (27:r_{27}(b)) = (27:21) = 3$

Thanks

Comment: @McFry I guess so, I edited